# ¿Cómo obtener un valor de una función ya usada, sin volverla a llamar a la función principal?

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo dos funciones creadas para éste proyecto, la primera llamada `myDinko()` y la segunda `verifica()`.

El código de la primera función es:

```
  function myDinko() {
  var lista = [
          {
            pregunta : "¿Por qué las flores son de colores?",
            tags :  [/fotosíntesis|pigmentación/]
          }, {
            pregunta : "¿Por qué la basura huele mal?",
            tags : [/descomposición|pudre/]
          }, {
            pregunta : "¿Por qué no puedo arrugar las botellas de plástico?",
            tags : [ /resistencia|componentes/ ]
          }, {
            pregunta : "¿Puede un árbol matar a un ser humano?",
            tags: [ /gravedad|fuerza/ ]
          }, {
            pregunta : "¿La basura nos hace mal?",
            tags : [/contaminantes|bacteria/]
          }, {
            pregunta : "¿Cuántos tipos de desechos hay?",
            tags : [ /inorgánicos|orgánicos/]
          }, {
            pregunta : "¿Qué puedo hacer con mi basura?",
            tags : [ /reducir|reciclaje/, /reutilizar|crear/]
          }, {
            pregunta : "¿Cómo se relaciona mi basura con las plantas?",
            tags : [ /contaminación|deforestación/]
          }, {
            pregunta : "¿Puedo cocinar con basura en lugar de leña?",
            tags : [ /reutilizar|contaminación/]
          }, {
            pregunta : "¿Por qué la ropa no está hecha con empaques de ricitos?",
            tags : [ /resistencia|reciclaje/]
          }, {
            pregunta : "¿Por qué se forman los charcos?",
            tags : [ /Ciclo del agua| recurso natural/]
          }]
    var item = lista[Math.floor(Math.random()*lista.length)];
    document.getElementById("preguntaDinko").innerHTML = item.pregunta;
    console.log(item.tags[0]);}
```

Con lo que he logrado obtener la pregunta al azar, pero debo verificar que el usuario ingrese los tags en su respuesta.

```
   <div class="row">
            <form class="col s9">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s9">
                  <textarea id="respuesta" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
                  <label for="icon_prefix2">Respuesta: </label>
                </div>

                <div class="input-field col s3">
                  <a class="btn-floating z-depth-5 modal-action modal-close btn-large waves-effect waves-light red tooltiped" data-tooltip="Enviar" onclick="verifica()" ><i class="material-icons">send</i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
```

Me he guíado del último ejemplo de ésta página: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Conciste en verificar si el usuario ingresa o no alguno de los tags que corresponden a cada pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear un objeto que mantenga internamente la pregunta actual. Así cuando ejecutas la función de verificación sabes que tags aplicar:

```js
function myDinko() {
  var lista = [
    {
      pregunta : "¿Por qué las flores son de colores?",
      tags :  [/fotosíntesis|pigmentación/]
    }, {
      pregunta : "¿Por qué la basura huele mal?",
      tags : [/descomposición|pudre/]
    }, {
      pregunta : "¿Por qué no puedo arrugar las botellas de plástico?",
      tags : [/resistencia|componentes/]
    }, {
      pregunta : "¿Puede un árbol matar a un ser humano?",
      tags: [/gravedad|fuerza/]
    }, {
      pregunta : "¿La basura nos hace mal?",
      tags : [/contaminantes|bacteria/]
    }, {
      pregunta : "¿Cuántos tipos de desechos hay?",
      tags : [/inorgánicos|orgánicos/]
    }, {
      pregunta : "¿Qué puedo hacer con mi basura?",
      tags : [/reducir|reciclaje/, /reutilizar|crear/]
    }, {
      pregunta : "¿Cómo se relaciona mi basura con las plantas?",
      tags : [/contaminación|deforestación/]
    }, {
      pregunta : "¿Puedo cocinar con basura en lugar de leña?",
      tags : [/reutilizar|contaminación/]
    }, {
      pregunta : "¿Por qué la ropa no está hecha con empaques de ricitos?",
      tags : [/resistencia|reciclaje/]
    }, {
      pregunta : "¿Por qué se forman los charcos?",
      tags : [/Ciclo del agua| recurso natural/]
    }];
  var preguntaActual;

  var mostrarPregunta = function(){
    preguntaActual = Math.floor(Math.random()*lista.length);
    var item = lista[preguntaActual];
    document.getElementById("preguntaDinko").innerHTML = item.pregunta;
    console.log(item.tags[0]);
  }
  
  var verificar = function(){
    var respuesta = document.getElementById("respuesta").value;
    var correcta = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < lista[preguntaActual].tags.length; i++){
      var resultado = lista[preguntaActual].tags[i].exec(respuesta);
      var correcta = resultado && resultado.length ? true : false;
      if (!correcta) break;
    }
    console.log(correcta);
    return correcta;
  }
  
  document.getElementById("botonEnviar").addEventListener("click", verificar);
  
  return {
    mostrarPregunta: mostrarPregunta
  };
}  

var quest = myDinko();
quest.mostrarPregunta();
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12" id="preguntaDinko"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <form class="col s9">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s9">
        <textarea id="respuesta" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
        <label for="icon_prefix2">Respuesta: </label>
      </div>

      <div class="input-field col s3">
        <a class="btn-floating z-depth-5 modal-action modal-close btn-large waves-effect waves-light red tooltiped" data-tooltip="Enviar" id="botonEnviar" ><i class="material-icons">send</i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

no entiendo muy bien tu pregunta pero si lo que buscas es una forma de comparar
puedes utilizar [regExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)  con la propiedad tags del objeto que tienes de forma aleatoria

```
var tags = new regExp(item.tags);
```

y luego comprar con el resultado

```
tags.test(resultado);
```

Answer (score 0):

Porqué no le asignas a cada pregunta un UID, cosa que puedes obtener información de la pregunta por el. Cuando insertes la pregunta en el elemento también añade como atributo `data-uid` el uid de la pregunta.

```
var preguntas = [
    {
        uid: 001,
        contenido: 'xxxxx',
        tags: 'tag1,tag2,tag3'
    }
];

var pregunta = preguntas[Math.floor(Math.random() * preguntas.length)];
var elemento = document.getElementById('preguntaDinko');
elemento.innerHTML = pregunta.contenido;
elemento.setAttribute('data-uid', pregunta.uid);
```

Así, por medio del UID obtenemos los tags de la pregunta y comparamos con los que se ingresen.

```
function verifica() {
    var uid = this.getAttribute('data-uid');
    var tags = obtenerTags(uid);
    var ingresados = /* */
    if(coincidenTags(tags, ingresados)) {
        // hacer algo
    }
}

function obtenerTags(uid) {
    preguntas.forEach(function(pregunta) {
       if(pregunta.hasOwnProperty('uid')) {
           if(pregunta.uid === uid) {
               return pregunta.tags;
           }
       }
    });
}

function coincidenTags(originales, ingresados) {
   if(originales.length !== ingresados.length) return false;
   for(let i = originales.length; i--;) {
     if(originales[i] !== ingresados[i]) return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```